# Twilio checking if human representative is on the line

Tags: twilio

I'm thinking of a scenario where web app with twilio api first makes an outbound call to a customer service number, send digits to get transferred to the agent, and instead of waiting on hold, I would like the web app to detect when human picks up the call and calls the user's phone number. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

There isn't an automated way to detect that a human has answered the call.  You could put a prompt in the phone call that the agent can input in order to indicate that they have answered the call.  Something like:

```
<Response>
    <Gather action="process/" numDigits="1">
        <Say>Please press one to connect to the incoming call</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.